# wget skipping index.html for links not ending in slashes when using --mirror

Tags: wget

I'm using wget --mirror --convert-links to mirror a web site, and I find that when the site contains a link to a subdirectory like:

```
<a href="subdir">
```

which would display the contents of subdir/index.html in a web browser, wget is fetching the documents that are linked to in the index.html, but not the index.html itself.

If I change the link to:

```
<a href="subdir/">
```

then the index.html is also fetched.

Is there a flag I can put on the wget command to get it to do this automatically?

I'm using wget version 1.14 under CentOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

Wget should save the page as `subdir`. Target path and filename are based on the link structure (and not on the final URLs after applying any redirections).

You could add option `-E` to save the document as `subdir.html`. I know, it's not perfect.

Comment: What I find is that wget creates a directory called subdir, and that contains any files with URLs of the form "subdir/file.html".  But the index for that subdirectory (index.html) is never fetched.

Comment: According to my log the index is fetched, but gets overwritten by the subdirectory with the same name if there are files under `subdir`. :(

Comment: Bummer.  It would be nice if wget let me supply a file name to be used for the index in cases like that.  E.g., "--index-file=index.html".

Comment: There is one, `--default-page=xxx` (default `index.html`), but that only works for links with slashes (`subdir/`). Have you tried `-E`?

Comment: -E doesn't do it (and it also mis-names some files that really should have extensions other than .html).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem too. It seems to be long known and impossible to do that with pure `wget`. I opened an [issue on wget tracker](https://gitlab.com/gnuwget/wget/-/issues/11). Here I propose several solutions I came up with.

### Manually download directories

First, you need to download all you can:

> wget -c --no-check-certificate --recursive --page-requisites --no-clobber --domains mysite.org --exclude-directories=/login https://mysite.org

Then, manually `find` a list of local directories (`-type d`) you need to save:

```
find mysite.org -path 'mysite.org/static' -prune -o -type d
```

Since *static* won't likely be browsed by people, we don't save it as *index.html*, and `find` action `-prune` disables search on that path. It is explained in more details on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1489405/952234). When you want to disable several paths, use parentheses. The full script would be:

```
for dir in `find mysite.org \( \
        -path 'mysite.org/static' -o \
        -path 'mysite.org/media' \)
    -prune -o -type d`
do
    echo $dir
    wget --force-directories $dir -O $dir/index.html
done
```

Since we download files one by one, we save them with full local path with `--force-directories` (otherwise they would be saved to the current directory). Also, we need to manually provide the output file name with `-O` option (otherwise `wget` will refuse to save the result to an existent directory).

Unfortunately, `find` will also list directories `static` and `media`, so you can use `grep` after that (I ignored that). You could also have saved the needed directory names to a file and use that with `wget -i links.txt` - however, in that case you wouldn't be able to provide output file names for those links.

### Download only directories

I tried to download only directories (links ending on slash) with:

```
wget -pr -A '/,index.html' https://mysite.org/
```

Here, `-A/--accept` is a comma-separated list of file name suffixes or patterns to accept. `-p`, as before, is to save page requisites (it also conserves local directory structure) and `-r` is for recursive. The first suffix means that we have a directory (ending with '/'), while the second is necessary to save that: without that the resulting *index.html* will be immediately deleted.

Unfortunately, this didn't work for my site, because some links ended with slashes, and some did not. There is no way to otherwise distinguish a "directory" path from a final link, and a slash in the end of a link looks like a redundant symbol, so I gave up this idea.

### Final remarks

Downloading a site can take a while, so if you do it from a server and want to disconnect after some time, use `nohup`.

I'd like to mention a curious thing I discovered. Sometimes `wget` saved html pages together with server response, that is one could see at the start of a page several lines of technical information ("HTTP/1.1 200 OK", etc). I'm not sure whether that was a problem with `wget` or with my old `nginx` server, but it can also be manually fixed by re-downloading the broken pages:

```
grep -RIl nginx * > bad.txt
wget -x -i bad.txt
```

Make sure to remove broken pages first, because `wget` won't re-download them if they exist (I could not find a key to overwrite that without `-r` or `-p`).

Maybe this detail is not relevant to the question, but it shows that a manual intervention could still be needed for `wget` results, and you should be ready for that.